# R - Conditional labels in data frames based on index values, without loops

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, conditional-statements

R question! I am trying to label rows in a data frame based on their indices. For example, I want to label all rows with an index < x "A", all rows with an index >= x and < y "B", etc. These index values are NOT constant, but will change from file to file that I am processing.

I have a huge data frame with thousands of rows, so I am trying to avoid lots of loops... I made a column of index values in my data frame, and I want to compare those values to a vector of values in order to strategically label rows in my data frame. This is the structure I want to avoid (I tried it and it works, it just takes forever):

```
for (i in 1:nrow(dataframe)){
  for (j in 1:length(index_values)){
    if (dataframe$Index[i]>index_values[j] & dataframe$Index[i]<index_values[j+1]{
      dataframe$Label[i]='blah'
    }
  }
}
```

I tried using "ifelse", but it doesn't seem to work in a loop? This is what I tried, but the "Label" field was not populated with anything.

```
for (i in 1:length(index_values)){
dataframe$Label <- ifelse((dataframe$Index>index_value[i] & dataframe$Index<index_value[i+1]),'blah',0) 
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to get "ifelse" to work in this context, or any other more efficient ways to approach this? 
Thanks!!

```
This is the result of dput(head(dataframe, 20))... the column I want to populate is the one called "PEPMASSLabel", you can ignore the one that says "Label2":

structure(list(Data = c("BEGIN IONS", "PEPMASS=81.52200", 
"MSLEVEL=1", "CHARGE=1+", "100.1120 4121.67 ", "101.0592 3174.14 ", 
"          102.1273 13152.36 ", "          103.9552 3842.30 ", 
"          104.1066 4018.44 ", "          111.0437 3431.08 ", 
"          113.9635 4037.19 ", "          114.0912 7486.78 ", 
"          116.0708 4411.26 ", "          117.0541 3008.86 ", 
"          118.0862 37381.12 ", "          118.1225 8411.46 ", 
"          124.0241 12898.76 ", "          127.0385 6135.08 ", 
"          128.9509 5558.22 ", "          129.0407 8047.48 "), 
    PEPMASSLabel = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Index = 1:20, PEPMASSLabel2 = 
c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = 
c("Data", "PEPMASSLabel", "Index", "PEPMASSLabel2"), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want the "Label" column to be populated by different text strings.

Comment: Can you share the output of `dput(head(dataframe, 20))` at the end of your question? Also show expected output.

Comment: yup, just did, though the output is a bit chaotic. sorry about that.

Comment: `cut(dataframe$Index, breaks=c(-Inf, x, y, Inf), labels=c("A", "B", "unk"))`

Comment: The cut function works great!!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

dplyr::case_when could also be applied here, though not as concise as `cut`.

```
# define these for each file
breaks <- c(2, 3, 7, 10, 15)

Data <- Data %>%
  mutate(Label = case_when(Index < breaks[1] ~ "A",
                           Index < breaks[2] ~ "B",
                           Index < breaks[3] ~ "C",
                           Index < breaks[4] ~ "D",
                           Index < breaks[5] ~ "E",
                           TRUE ~ "Z"))


> head(Data)
               Data PEPMASSLabel Index PEPMASSLabel2 Label
1        BEGIN IONS            0     1             0     A
2  PEPMASS=81.52200            0     2             0     B
3         MSLEVEL=1            0     3             0     C
4         CHARGE=1+            0     4             0     C
5 100.1120 4121.67             0     5             0     C
6 101.0592 3174.14             0     6             0     C
```